# NodeJS run python script

Tags: python, node.js

I found some articles but still I could not done it.

My index.js nodejs

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const {PythonShell} = require("python-shell");


router.get('/ne', (req, res, next)=> {

    console.log("here");
    PythonShell.run('sam.py', {
      args: ['hello']
      }, function (err, results) {   
          console.log("here2");
        if(results)
        { 
           console.log(results);
         }
        if(err)
            { 
             console.log(err);
            }
        });
      });

module.exports = router;
```

Sample python file for me which name is sam.py, they are in same folder

```
import sys
import os

print("first")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("second")
    a = sys.argv[1]

    if not os.path.exists(a):
            os.makedirs(a)
    print("after")
```

When I try to get here,

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www`
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www`
here
here2
```

So, routing is working but I can not start the python script

Comment: "nothing happens" is not a problem description. Does your server even start? If so, does your route handler even work? (try a `console.log`). Do you you make it into the python script? (try a `print()`). Do you make it into your `if not...`? (again, try a `print()`). Do you make it into your err/result handler? (again, try a `console.log`).  _Some_ debugging on your part before posting is [always required](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sory for that. When I try go get here means my serves is running  and the route "/ne" is running console.log() they both work

Comment: No, don't tell _me_ that, tell _everyone_ that, by updating your post to make it clear which parts run, which parts don't run, and what you've already tried to figure out why that is. There are [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) that you really need to read through, so you can update your post accordingly.

Comment: Okay sorry, I fixed

Comment: where are the other console.logs on the Node side (add at least one in your python callback), and the `print(...)` statements at the various levels in your python script (add three, at the top level, one inside the first if block, and one more inside the second if block)?

Comment: Yes, Python is not running

Comment: I am still not seeing any `console.log` in your result handler which is pretty important because _if there was an error, that is where you will be told about it_  which is why you should always have `function(err, result) { if (err) { console.error(err); } }` at the _very_ least. How else will you know what went wrong?

Comment: i test your sample js code and run server and then run python source code and create hello directory with call localhost:4000 route, without any error!!!

Comment: It works fine, `console.log(results)` in that callback for `PythonShell.run`.

Comment: Okay finally I fixed, It creates but for up folder. now I can make it. Thank all of you